# Is the state of previous git bisect "sessions" stored somewhere in git?

Tags: git, bisect

Some time ago I used git bisect to identify a bad commit, which I managed to. I then closed the git bisect "session" with `git bisect reset`.
However, my process to identify whether a commit is good/bad is rather complex, and I may have made a mistake.

My question is whether I can "reload" the closed git bisect session to manually retest the good/bad status of the commits I have evaluated in the process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently I should have used ```git bisect log >file.txt``` when bisecting, and then use ```git bisect replay file.txt```. I' m wondering whether automatically storing these logs would be a desirable git feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in, automated "bisect history".

You can run `git bisect log` to store the *current* session's progress to a file and later use `git bisect replay` to re-run the previous session up to the point in the log.